# Javascript encode/decode field

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a field which I encode/decode using the following

i.e. when the user updates in the child modal, I do

```
self.options.eventDispatcher.trigger("updateMyField", encodeURIComponent(myFieldVal));
```

and I listen for this in the parent modal and say

```
$("#myFieldDiv").html(decodeURIComponent(response));
```

Here response is the field value.

Now my question is if I enter

```
<script>alert("1")</script>
```

I am getting an alert. How do I fix this, so that it does not alert but just writes it as text in my div myFieldDiv ?

Comment: do u want to write decoded url in myFieldDiv?

Comment: What do you want to print? And where?

Comment: embed it in <code> tags

Comment: Use `.txt()` instead of `.html()` ?

Comment: I have to use .html() and I want it to be printed as <script>alert("1")</script> in my div

Comment: Why do you "*have to use `html()`*"? It's the wrong tool for the job you describe.

Answer (score 1):

Try using $.text not $.html - `$("#myFieldDiv").text(decodeURIComponent(response));`

Answer (score 0):

Just don't decode it, write it encoded

```
$("#myFieldDiv").html(response);
```

EDIT

Replace `<` and `>` with html entities:

```
self.options.eventDispatcher.trigger("updateMyField", myFieldVal.replace(/[<>]/g, function(charToReplace){
    var chars = {
        '<': '&lt;',
        '>': '&gt;'
    }
    return chars[charToReplace];
    })
);
```

Comment: I want it to be printed as <script>alert("1")</script> in the div
Will this work ?

Answer (score 0):

Use `text()` to insert the value as it will encode any HTML it finds:

```
self.options.eventDispatcher.trigger("updateMyField", myFieldVal);

$("#myFieldDiv").text(response);
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/peadnmhp/)

Note that the fiddle only concatenates the `<script>` tag to get around JSFiddle's security settings.